# Python - Function Return Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, boolean

This example is just a basic program - I'm a new Coder - learning and experimenting whilst messing about .. Currently testing on Python 3.6 IDE and PyCharm - apologies for double spacing code - but looks a mess without.

Looking for guidance for returning a value from a function.

Have tried dozens of different methods / searched the forum, but closest answer this layman could understand stated I needed to use the return value otherwise it will be forgotten .. So added *print(age_verification, " example test value .. ")* at various locations - but nothing gets returned outside the function ..

Have tried returning Boolean / integer / string values and adapting - nothing with each variant .. Added a default *age_verification = False* variable before the function // or // referenced within function for 1st time .. Doesn't effect the return value except IDE doesn't state "unresolved reference"

Tried a line-by-line python visualizer - but again - age_verification value disappears instantly after exiting the function . :-(

==================================================================

**Using 1 Single Function**

```
def age_veri(age, age_verification) :

  if age < 18 :

    age_verification = False

    print(age_verification, " is false .. Printed to test variable ..")

    return age_verification

  elif age >= 18:

    age_verification = True

    print(age_verification, " is True.. Printed to test variable ..")

    return age_verification

  return age_verification # ( -- have tested with/without this single-indent line & with/without previous double-indent return age_verification line.)

age=int(input("Enter Your Age : ")

age_verification = False # ( -- have tried with / without this default value)

age_veri(age, False)

if age_verification is False:

  print("You failed Verification - Age is Below 18 .. ")

elif age_verification is True:

  print("Enter Website - Over 18yrs")

else:

  print(" Account not Verified .. ")
```

==================================================================

**Same Example - Using 2 Functions**

```
def age_variable(age):

   if age < 18:

      age_verification = False

      print (age_verification, " printing here to use value and help test function..")

      return age_verification

   elif age >= 18:

      age_verification = True

      print (age verification, " printing here to use value and help test function..")

      return age_verification

   return age_verification (tried with and without this line - single indent - same level as if / elif) 

def are_verified(age_verification):

   if age_verification is False:

      print("Age Verification Failed .. ")

   elif age_verification is True:

      print("Visit Website .. ")

   else:

      print("Verification Incomplete .. ")

age = int(input("Enter Your Age : ")

age_variable(age)

are_verified(age_verification)
```

==============================================================

Any advice is appreciated - wasted most of today hitting my head against the wall .. And apologies in advance .. Know it'll be something really basic - but appear to be using same formatting as others :-)

**THANK YOU**

Comment: To retain a returned value you must save it to a name (or variable, if you like). So if you had `def add(x, y): return x +y` then to use it you'd need to do something like `z = add(1, 6)`. Then `7` will be "saved" to `z`.

Comment: Thank you for your time .. It is appreciated ..

Comment: I've added age_verification = True ( or ) age_verification = False - is "age_verification" not a name ..?

Comment: Or are values only returned after computation (eg add / subtract / divide ) rather than reallocating a value from False -> True

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the second comment you just made, but as for `age_verification`: if a name is defined inside of a function it disappears once the function is over. See C.Nivs' answer, this is what "scope" is

Comment: Contemplate: `def add(x, y): z = x; return z +y` and then running it `z = add(1, 6)`. Same answer as before. `z` is one thing while inside the function; once the function is done it disappears. Outside the function the equal sign means the new `z` gets assigned the function's return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` doesn't return values, it will just display the value to `stdout` or the console. If you want to return a value with conditions, understanding scope is helpful. Your comment regarding returning variables otherwise they will be "forgotten" is correct. Variables defined and *not* returned by the function will go away when the function executes:

```
def my_func(var1):
    var2 = var1
    var3 = 5
    return var3

print(my_func(1), var2)
```

The `print` statement will throw a `NameError` because `var2` isn't defined outside of the function, nor is it returned. For your example, you'd want something like this:

```
def age_verify(age):
    if age < 18:
        print("Failed Verification")
        return False
    else:
        print("Verification Complete")
        return True

# Call and assign to var
age = int(input("Enter Your Age : ")
age_verification = age_verify(age)
```

This way you are saving the returned value as the variable `age_verification`

EDIT:

To further expand on the scope concept, using the same definition for `my_func`:

```
def my_func(var1):
    var2 = var1
    var3 = 5
    return var3
```

We assign the returned `var3` to a variable like so:

```
myvar = my_func(5)
```

As noted, the name `var3` isn't actually returned, just the value. If I were to run

```
myvar = my_func(5)
print(var3)
```

I would get a `NameError`. The way to get around that would be to do:

```
var3 = my_func(5)
```

because now `var3` is defined in global scope. Otherwise, I would have to edit my function to make `var3` global:

```
def my_func(var1):
    global var3
    var2 = var1
    var3 = 5
    # The return statement is then a bit redundant

my_func(5)

print(var3)
# prints 5 in global scope
```

Hopefully this is a bit clearer than my original answer

Comment: This is a good answer but I would edit slightly to make it clear that even if you had written `print(var3)` after defining `my_func`, it still wouldn't have worked. Saying " because var2 isn't defined outside of the function, nor is it returned" could be confusing to newbies. The *name* attached to a return value is not returned (unless you used `global`)